# Database Querying Issue with Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am running Android Studio on Mac OS 10.7.5. The app I am writing query's a database and I keep running into the problem of my query not working and producing 0 results with the same exact query. I have tested the Query in Firefox's SQLite manager and it yields the results I am looking for.

This issue does not happen every time either. I will leave work with it working and get home and it will not or vice versa. To try and debug I have hard coded a valid query and there are still no results. However when the code is working the hard coded query and my other method of querying work without issue.

I have tried changing the build settings to use external build under Preferences / Compiler / Use External Build, because of this error:

```
10:56:27 PM Deprecated make implementation
        Old implementation of "Make" feature is enabled for this project.
        It has been deprecated and will be removed soon.
        Please enable newer 'external build' feature in Settings | Compiler.
```

In the event log, and that made it worked for a little while and then the error returned. I have also tried updating Android Studio which also fixed it one time but the issue again returned. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you may need more information.

```
public class DBAccess extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private SQLiteDatabase database;

public static String TABLE_PATH = "";

public static final String COLUMN_ROWID = "rowid";
public static final String COLUMN_LASTNAME = "lastname";
public static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employeedb.sqlite";
private static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "employee";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation SQL statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "create table "
        + TABLE_EMPLOYEE  + "("
        + COLUMN_ROWID    + " text, "
        + COLUMN_LASTNAME    + " text, "
        + COLUMN_FIRSTNAME    + " text"
        + ");";

public DBAccess(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    TABLE_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(Constants.databaseName).toString();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    }catch (SQLException e) {}
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    database.close();
}

public ArrayList<Person> searchSQLWithPrefix(String prefix, String[] params) {
    ArrayList<Person> results = new ArrayList<Person>();


    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT lastname, firstname FROM employee " +
            "WHERE UPPER(lastname) like UPPER('Smith') OR UPPER(firstname) like " +
            "UPPER('Smith') ORDER BY firstname, lastname LIMIT 1000", null);

    //Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(prefix, params);

    if (cursor != null) {
        return setPeople(cursor);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return results;
}

public ArrayList<Person> setPeople(Cursor cursor) {
    ArrayList<Person> results = new ArrayList<Person>();
    Log.e("Test", "Cursor Count: " + cursor.getCount());

    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Person p = new Person( cursor, cursor.getPosition() );
            results.add( p );
    }
    return results;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are displaying your results in the UI somewhere, so if you are using a Listview, ExpandedListView, etc. android view's require that there is a column _id in your table and is retrieved in your query so that the view can keep in sync with the data adapter's data from your database cursor via the _id column.

I have never had to use the

```
cursor.close();
```

So that brings the question of how are you managing your cursor and that really depends on which what version you are targeting for your application.  For Honeycomb and later I would look at 'cursor loader', and prior to that 'startManagingCursor' was used, but I believe it recommend to user cursor loaders, this will eliminate the need for you to close the cursor.  Since the cursor is a async type task, you could be closing the cursor prior to it returning any results.

For cursor loaders I would suggest [How to use loaders in Android](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/)

You can also search for code at github.com or code.google.com, etc.

If you need _id for any reason, you could fake out your query with this in your projection:

```
id as _id,
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am displaying my results in the UI which has worked with using column rowid instead of column _id. The problem is that currently I cannot get the cursor to return any results. I have even tried this statement `Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employee;", null);` and I still get a cursor count of 0.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue was that my database already exists and I was creating a new one with and empty table, hence the 0 results. Thanks for the help and I will take a look at using cursor loaders as a better solution.